# CSS Formatting not available in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2012, I can go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS -> Formatting to set how I want the CSS to be formatting (Compact rules, semi-expanded, expanded).

I am not seeing the Formatting option in Visual Studio 2013. Has that been moved to somewhere else? This is a screenshot of what I see:

[image: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's available as a dropdown under Advanced -> Formatting -> Brace positions.

Comment: I kind of liked the way VS 2012 did it with the example for you to see. Oh well. Thanks for the answer!